# Regex to delete page breaks during .mobi to .pdf conversion?

Tags: regex, pdf, calibre

I'm trying to use Calibre's Search and Replace feature to delete a lot of unnecessary page breaks while converting a file from .mobi to .pdf. In Calibre's "Search" box, I have entered:

```
(?s)<div class="mbp_pagebreak"></div>
```

This seems to correctly select all of the page breaks. In the "Replace" box, I just put a space, thinking that would essentially delete all of the selected code, but nothing seemed to happen. I then tried putting in the string "Test." to see what exactly was happening. In this case, the word "Test." was written before each page break, but the breaks were all still there. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the engine they use PCRE ?

Comment: Sound's like it's replacing with the replacement text plus the match text. But, it shouldn't be doing that by default. Or, something like this `(?=<div class="mbp_pagebreak"></div>)` will cause that.

Comment: what's the (?s) for? that's not valid regex...